# Does the Constitution of Bhutan state that 60% of Bhutan must be forested?

Tags: law, environment, bhutan

[image: Did you know? The constitution of Bhutan specifies that 60% of the country must remain forested. - MightyFacts.com]

Transcription:

> **Did you know?**
>
> The constitution of Bhutan specifies that 60% of the country must remain forested.
>
> -- MightyFacts.com

Title and picture is pretty self explanatory. Is the picture right?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

[The Constitution of the Kingdom of Bhutan](http://www.bhutanaudit.gov.bt/About%20Us/Mandates/Constitution%20of%20Bhutan%202008.pdf), Article 5, paragraph 3:

> The Government shall ensure that, in order to conserve the
>   country’s natural resources and to prevent degradation of the
>   ecosystem, a minimum of sixty percent of Bhutan’s total land
>   shall be maintained under forest cover for all time.

Comment: They publish their constitution in English?

Comment: @EMBLEM: The national language is Dzongkha but the English version seems to be an official translation.  See http://www.nab.gov.bt/en/business/constitution_of_bhutan

Comment: relevant: https://www.ted.com/talks/tshering_tobgay_this_country_isn_t_just_carbon_neutral_it_s_carbon_negative

Comment: Even if it weren't an "official" translation, it seems fairly clear-cut - not much room for a translation error.